# Logistic regression parameter P-value changes after logarithm - R

Tags: r, logistic-regression, logarithm, p-value

I have an issue when calculating logistic regression in R that, to me, makes no sense.
I have one parameter in the model, positive numbers (molecular weight).
I have a binary response variable, let's say either A or B.
My data table is called df1.

`str(df1)`

```
data.frame':    1015 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Protein_Class: chr  "A" "A" "A" "B" ...
 $ MW                  : num  47114 29586 26665 34284 104297 ...
```

I make the model:

```
summary(glm(as.factor(df1[,1]) ~ df1[,2],family="binomial"))
```

The results are:

```
Call:
glm(formula = as.factor(df1[, 1]) ~ df1[, 2], family = "binomial")

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.5556  -1.5516   0.8430   0.8439   0.8507  

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  8.562e-01  1.251e-01   6.842  7.8e-12 ***
df1[, 2]    -1.903e-07  3.044e-06  -0.063     0.95    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 1239.2  on 1014  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 1239.2  on 1013  degrees of freedom
AIC: 1243.2

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

That's all fine and good until this point.
But, when I take the logarithm of my variable:

```
summary(glm(as.factor(df1[,1]) ~ log10(df1[,2]),family="binomial"))
```

```
Call:
glm(formula = as.factor(df1[, 1]) ~ log10(df1[, 2]), family = "binomial")

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.8948  -1.4261   0.8007   0.8528   1.0469  

Coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
(Intercept)      -2.7235     1.1169  -2.438  0.01475 * 
log10(df1[, 2])   0.8038     0.2514   3.197  0.00139 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 1239.2  on 1014  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 1228.9  on 1013  degrees of freedom
AIC: 1232.9

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

The p-value has changed!
How can this be? And more importantly, which one to use?
My understanding was that logistic regression is based on ranks, and all I do is a monotone transformation. Note, that the AUROC curve of the model remains the same.
There are no zero or negative values that are lost during the transformation.

Did I miss something here?
Any advice?

Thanks in advance,

Adam

Comment: Logistic regression is not just based on ranks; the coefficients are estimated by finding the ones that maximize the likelihood of the data given the coefficients in a linear predictor. If you change the nature of the variables in the linear predictor, everything can change. The AUROC is the same because as you note the log is a monotone transformation and the AUC relies on the ordering of the test statistics, not their actual values.

Comment: Thanks!
This however begs the question of which transformation, if any, to use?
In many cases there is no expected association between a variable and the response. The square root, square, log all give different p-values, but the correct association, I would presume, is between one form of the parameter and the response.

Comment: Answered below.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things to think about.  First, you can probably constrain your search to one side or the other of 1.  That is decreasing the power on `x` - square root, log, inverse, etc... - all have a similar type of effect, but to differing degrees.  They all pull in big values and spread out small values.  The transformations greater than 1 do the opposite, they tend to increase the spread among big values and decrease the spread among small values - all generally assuming you've got no non-positive values in your variable.  This is really, then, a question about what kind of transformation you want and then after that - how severe does it have to be.

First, what kind of transformation do you need. I made some fake data to illustrate the point:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1234)
x <- runif(1000, 1, 10000)
y.star <- -6 + log(x)
y <- rbinom(1000, 1, plogis(y.star) )
df <- tibble(
  y=y, 
  x=x, 
  ystar=y.star)
```

Next, since this is just a bivariate relationship, we could plot it out with a loess curve.  In particular, though, we want to know what the log-odds of y look like with respect to x.  We can do this by transforming the predictions from the loess curve with the logistic quantile function, `qlogis()` - this takes the probabilities and puts them in log-odds form.  Then, we could make the plot.

```
lo <- loess(y ~ x, span=.75)
df <- df %>% mutate(fit = predict(lo), 
             fit = case_when(
               fit < .01 ~ .01, 
               fit > .99 ~ .99, 
               TRUE ~ fit))
ggplot(df) + 
  geom_line(aes(x=x, y=qlogis(fit)))
```

[image]

This looks like a class log relationship.  We could then implement a few different transformations and plot those - square root, log and negative inverse.

```
lo1 <- loess(y ~ sqrt(x), span=.5)
lo2 <- loess(y ~ log(x), span=.5)
lo3 <- loess(y ~ I(-(1/x)), span=.5)

df <- df %>% mutate(fit1 = predict(lo1), 
                    fit1 = case_when(
                      fit1 < .01 ~ .01, 
                      fit1 > .99 ~ .99, 
                      TRUE ~ fit1))
df <- df %>% mutate(fit2 = predict(lo2), 
                    fit2 = case_when(
                      fit2 < .01 ~ .01, 
                      fit2 > .99 ~ .99, 
                      TRUE ~ fit2))
df <- df %>% mutate(fit3 = predict(lo3), 
                    fit3 = case_when(
                      fit3 < .01 ~ .01, 
                      fit3 > .99 ~ .99, 
                      TRUE ~ fit3))
```

Next, we need to transform the data so the plotting will look right:

```
plot.df <- df %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols=starts_with("fit"), 
                      names_to="var", 
                      values_to="vals") %>% 
  mutate(x2 = case_when(
    var == "fit" ~ x, 
    var == "fit1" ~ sqrt(x), 
    var == "fit2" ~ log(x), 
    var == "fit3" ~ -(1/x), 
    TRUE ~ x), 
  var = factor(var, labels=c("Original", "Square Root", "Log", "Inverse")))
```

Then, we can make the plot:

```
ggplot(plot.df, aes(x=x2, y=vals)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  facet_wrap(~var, scales="free_x")
```

[image]

Here, it looks like the log is the most linear of the bunch - not surprising since we made the variable `y.star` with `log(x)`.  If we wanted to test between these different possibilities, Kevin Clarke, a Political Scientist at Rochester proposed a paired sign test for evaluating the difference between non-nested models.  There is a paper about it [here](https://www.kevinclarke.org/uploads/1/1/0/1/110167375/sdft.pdf).  I wrote a package called `clarkeTest` that implements this in R.  So, we could use this to test the various different alternatives:

```
m0 <- glm(y ~ x, data=df, family=binomial)
m1 <- glm(y ~ sqrt(x), data=df, family=binomial)
m2 <- glm(y ~ log(x), data=df, family=binomial)
m3 <- glm(y ~ I(-(1/x)), data=df, family=binomial)
```

Testing the original against the square root:

```
library(clarkeTest)
> clarke_test(m0, m1)
# 
# Clarke test for non-nested models
# 
# Model 1 log-likelihood: -309
# Model 2 log-likelihood: -296
# Observations: 1000
# Test statistic: 400 (40%)
# 
# Model 2 is preferred (p = 2.7e-10)
```

This shows that the square root is better than the original un-transformed variable.

```
clarke_test(m0, m2)
# 
# Clarke test for non-nested models
# 
# Model 1 log-likelihood: -309
# Model 2 log-likelihood: -284
# Observations: 1000
# Test statistic: 462 (46%)
# 
# Model 2 is preferred (p = 0.018)
```

The above shows that the log is better than the un-transformed variable.

```
> clarke_test(m0, m3)
# 
# Clarke test for non-nested models
# 
# Model 1 log-likelihood: -309
# Model 2 log-likelihood: -292
# Observations: 1000
# Test statistic: 550 (55%)
# 
# Model 1 is preferred (p = 0.0017)
```

The above shows that the un-transformed variable is preferred to the negative inverse. Then, we can test the difference of the two models preferred to the original.

```
> clarke_test(m1, m2)
# 
# Clarke test for non-nested models
# 
# Model 1 log-likelihood: -296
# Model 2 log-likelihood: -284
# Observations: 1000
# Test statistic: 536 (54%)
# 
# Model 1 is preferred (p = 0.025)
```

This shows that the the square root is better than the log transformation in terms of individual log-likelihoods.

Another option would be a grid search over possible transformations and look at the AIC each time.  We first have to make a function to deal with the situation where the transformation power = 0, where we should substitute the log.  Then we can run a model for each different transformation and get the AICs.

```
grid <- seq(-1,1, by=.1)

trans <- function(x, power){
  if(power == 0){
    tx <- log(x)
  }else{
    tx <- x^power
  }
  tx
}
mods <- lapply(grid, function(p)glm(y ~ trans(x, p),
                                    data=df, 
                                    family=binomial))
aic.df <- tibble(
  power = grid, 
  aic = sapply(mods, AIC))
```

Next, we can plot the AICs as a function of the power.

```
ggplot(aic.df, aes(x=power, y=aic)) + 
  geom_line()
```

This tells us that about -.25 is the appropriate transformation parameter.  Note that there is a discrepancy between the Clarke test results and the AIC because AIC is based on the *overall* log-likelihood and the Clarke test is based on differences in the *individual* log-likelihoods.

We would find that this new proposed transformation is also worse than the square root:

```
m4 <- glm(y ~ I(x^-.25), data=df, family=binomial)
clarke_test(m1, m4)
# 
# Clarke test for non-nested models
# 
# Model 1 log-likelihood: -296
# Model 2 log-likelihood: -283
# Observations: 1000
# Test statistic: 559 (56%)
# 
# Model 1 is preferred (p = 0.00021)
```

So, if you have a couple of different candidates in mind and you like the idea behind the Clarke test, you could use that to find the appropriate transformation.  If you don't have a candidate in mind, a grid search is always a possibility.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the great answer!
I'll have to think about this.
Cheers,
Adam